# How to scroll div inside div while making another div non scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is i need that d1 scrolls on scrolling while d2 scroll only upto certain limit where d1 and d2 div are inside a single div D and scroll property is on div D not on d1 and d2

```
<div id="D" style="overflow:scroll;"> 
    <div id="d1">some content</div> 
    <div id="d2"> some content</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Code is missing ...!!!

Comment: scroll limit for d2 ?

Comment: <div id="D" style="overflow:scroll;">
  <div id="d1">some content</div>
  <div id="d2"> some content</div>
</div>

Comment: limit for d2 is only scrolling d2 till it's bottom end appears on the screen, after that d2 stops scrolling....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible to achieve without scripting it, which could be messy, considering the numerous events which scroll an element (click, scrollwheel, down arrow, space bar).

Suggestion : Easiest way to achieve this is to create your own scrollbar and do what u want on scroll event..

Comment: if it is possible through javascript or jquery how can i do it...any help regarding this will help a lot...